# Force strips with % width to moves like in marquee without blank space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a 5 strips with 20% of full width and different background-colors of each one and I want to animate this in that way:
1) All strips moves from left to right,
2) after ^ animation I want to keep moving this like in "marquee" case but I want to avoid a blank space and glitches after repeats (something like infinite horizontal scrolling).

I've tried to use a http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin#examples plugin, but it's doesn't work well in this case because of width and different background colors.

Maybe there is a way to use pure CSS3? Here's my sketch: http://jsfiddle.net/sbgrhtqv/

```
<div class="strips">
    <div class="strip"></div>
    <div class="strip"></div>
    <div class="strip"></div>
    <div class="strip"></div>
    <div class="strip"></div>
</div>

.strips {
    width:100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: slide;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.strip {
    height: 5px;
    width:20%;
    float: left;
}
.strip:nth-child(1) {background: red;}
.strip:nth-child(2) {background: purple;}
.strip:nth-child(3) {background: grey;}
.strip:nth-child(4) {background: green;}
.strip:nth-child(5) {background: blue;}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0%{
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
    }
}
```

Do you have any solutions? I'll be greatful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your animation to be infinite, you'll need to duplicate your strips because they cannot disappear to the right and fill the blank space on the left at the same time. I also added a container to hide the overflow and not get infinite horizontal scroll:

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%; height: 5px;
}

.strips {
    position: absolute; left: -100%; top: 0;
    width: 200%; height: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: slide 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:    slide 4s linear infinite;
    animation:         slide 4s linear infinite;
}

.strip { height: 5px; width: 10%; float: left; }

.strip:nth-child(1), .strip:nth-child(6) { background: red;    }
.strip:nth-child(2), .strip:nth-child(7) { background: purple; }
.strip:nth-child(3), .strip:nth-child(8) { background: grey;   }
.strip:nth-child(4), .strip:nth-child(9) { background: green;  }
.strip:nth-child(5), .strip:nth-child(10){ background: blue;   }

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(0);   }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(50%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide {
    0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(0);   }
    100% { -moz-transform: translateX(50%); }
}
@keyframes slide {
    0%   { transform: translateX(0);   }
    100% { transform: translateX(50%); }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="strips">
        <div class="strip"></div>
        <div class="strip"></div>
        <div class="strip"></div>
        <div class="strip"></div>
        <div class="strip"></div>
        <div class="strip"></div>
        <div class="strip"></div>
        <div class="strip"></div>
        <div class="strip"></div>
        <div class="strip"></div>
        <div class="strip"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```